# Is there a phase contrast method for SEM?

Tags: microscopy

I was searching in the literature, and I did not find any phase contrast method for SEM microscopy. I would like to to if there is any, and if it not why?

Comment: A little more info on what you are trying to do would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for response! I was reviewing the papers, I noticed that there are some phase contrast methods in TEM, but I couldn't find any for SEM, so I got curious.

Comment: Well, with TEM you get to do imaging with a diffracted beam which has no direct analog with SEM. You can do diffraction in an SEM (EBSD) to get phase information, various things around energy selection, etc.